# Bash - Using 'expect' with process substitution

Tags: bash

Trying to use process substituion `<()` inside `expect` to add a SSH key pair. Is this possible?

```
ssh_key="""
----PRIVATE-----
....
"""

expect <<- EOF
  spawn ssh-add <(echo "${ssh_key}")
  expect "Enter passphrase"
  send "$password"
  expect eof
EOF
```

**Error:**

```
Trying to add key to SSH agent...
extra characters after close-quote
    while executing
"spawn ssh-add <(echo "----PRIVATE-----
...."


Failed to add key to
```

Comment: In general, don't use `expect` for authentication. At least on macOS, you can store passphrases in your Keychain and use `ssh-add -A` to add keys using stored passphrases. Under Linux, the `keychain` program appears to provide similar functionality.

Comment: @anubhava, ssh-add expect a file, but I want process substitution. 
@chepner, reason for not using `expect`? `-A` is not an available option for me.

Comment: The short answer is no, you can't use process substitution. See [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents). `If [the delimiter] is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion...` No process substitutions.

Comment: @N.J That's why I mentioned `keychain` as well; `-A` is specific to the `ssh-add` program shipped with macOS, rather than a general option for interacting with arbitrary password managers.

Comment: Expect is not shell. It does not support shell's `<(cmd ...)`.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells what about pipe to stdin?

Comment: @N.J i think its much easier to use a tmp file.